# Fourier Expansion *NOT Fourier Transform* of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in the domain of $[-\pi:\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series

For the expansion I need the value of the integral of $a_o$ = $\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin{x}}{x} dx$. But I can't find an **easy understandable** way to integrate it. Instructor asked to do an inproper integral, but I couldn't. Can anyone here assist me how to exactly to it?

Comment: Scroll down [the WP page on the sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). You need to learn about the so called *sine integral*. In other words, the Fourier coefficients of this function cannot be written in terms of elementary functions (unless you include the sine integral among them :-). It is one of the first elementary functions without an elementary indefinite integral a calculus student is likely to encounter.

Comment: Type in the integrals to Wolfram Alpha (or Mathematica, or some other CAS, if available) to see what it spews out.